# Проблема TLS1.2 подключения RabbitMQ

Tags: config, rabbitmq, tls

**Ошибка c TLS 1.2:**

trace-log:

```
2024-01-29 00:00:21,152 [53] INFO  - Error creating read connection, EndPoint: amqp://rabbit-t4.isb:5671, SSL enabled: True,  SSL Version: Tls12,  Reason: None of the specified endpoints were reachable.
024-01-29 00:00:21,162 [53] INFO  - Ошибка создания подписки. EndPoint: amqp://rabbit-t4.isb:5671, Exchange: q_dx, VirtualHost: [smev_svedflmob_q_req_q], Queue: . Причина: None of the specified endpoints were reachable. Метод: RabbitMqProcessor.Subscribe

exceptions:

2024-01-29 00:00:06,167 [33] ERROR - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2024-01-29 00:00:36,148 [66] ERROR - RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption sslOption)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, Int32 connectionTimeout, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at SMEVI.Components.UC.AppServices.ChannelService.MqRabbitConnectionManagers.MqRabbitInputConnectionManager..ctor(ConnectionFactory factory)
   at SMEVI.Components.UC.AppServices.ChannelService.MqRabbitConnectionManagers.MqRabbitInputConnectionManager.GetInstance(ConnectionFactory factory)
```

Строка подключения с TLS 1.2:

```
    <!--<add key="rmq.dir.out" value="amqps://rabbit-t4.isb:5671/quorumsmev_dx//smev_svedflmob_q_req_q" />-->
    <!--<add key="rmq.dir.in" value="amqps://rabbit-t4.isb:5671/quorumsmev_dx//smev_mobilsmev_q_res_q" />-->
```

**Ошибка без TLS 1.2:**

024-01-29 00:00:21,162 [53] INFO  - Ошибка создания подписки. EndPoint: amqp://rabbit-t4.isb:5671, Exchange: q_dx, VirtualHost: [smev_svedflmob_q_req_q], Queue: . Причина: None of the specified endpoints were reachable. Метод: RabbitMqProcessor.Subscribe

Строка подключения без TLS 1.2:

```
<add key="rmq.dir.out" value="amqp://rabbit-t4.isb:5672/q_dx//smev_svedflmob_q_req_q" />
<add key="rmq.dir.in" value="amqp://rabbit-t4.isb:5672/q_dx//smev_mobilsmev_q_res_q" />
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Для начала проверьте, что у вас RabbitMQ работает. Например, `echo -e 'HELLO\n\n\n\n' | nc rabbit-t4.isb 5672` и убедитесь, что в консоли будет напечатано `AMQP`. Если нет, значит сервер недоступен - не работает или не принимает входящие запросы